# how to covert this sql query string to solr query

Tags: javascript, solr

Hello I've got thos query in my web service in java which selects all the records from biz_subjec field which start with the specific string

```
"select biz_subject from pl_biz WHERE biz_subject ILIKE '"+ myel + "%'";
```

So today I've instaled solr and with a lot of efforts - indexed my database! And now i should start making queries! BUt it seems no matter how much i read I cant understand the syntax 
So i;m asking for help and if you can send me some good articles and documentation with a lot of examples so I can unederstand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Solr Query Syntax](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html)

For a like query you would need to fire a [wildcard query](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Wildcard+Queries).

So for a field biz_subject you would need to fire `biz_subject=myvel*`

Comment: i suppose my string for myel= lir should look like localhost:8983/solr/db/select?q=biz_subject%3Alir*&wt=xml&indent=true    by the way why we write %3A,